# Install specific git commit with pip

Tags: git, installation, commit, pip

I'm developing a django app and I'm using pip to manage my requirements. How can I do to install a specific git's commit?

In my case I need to install this commit:
https://github.com/aladagemre/django-notification/commit/2927346f4c513a217ac8ad076e494dd1adbf70e1

Answer (score 484, accepted):

You can specify commit hash, branch name, tag.

For the branch name and the tag, you can also install a compressed distribution. This is faster and more efficient, as it does not require cloning the entire repository. GitHub creates those bundles automatically.

**hash:**

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/aladagemre/django-notification.git@2927346f4c513a217ac8ad076e494dd1adbf70e1
```

**branch-name**

With git

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/aladagemre/django-notification.git@cool-feature-branch
```

or from source bundle

```
$ pip install https://github.com/aladagemre/django-notification/archive/cool-feature-branch.tar.gz
```

**tag**

with git

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/aladagemre/django-notification.git@v2.1.0
```

or from source bundle

```
$ pip install https://github.com/aladagemre/django-notification/archive/v2.1.0.tar.gz
```

It is a not well-documented feature, but you can find more information at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/vcs-support/

Comment: It will add this fun message: `Could not find a tag or branch '2927346f4c513a217ac8ad076e494dd1adbf70e1', assuming commit.`

Comment: @vlad-ardelean any idea on how to tell pip IT IS a commit? This is getting outputed on my deploy script and I don't want to suppress all stderr.

Comment: If you do not specify anything, what is the behavior?

Comment: @ScottStafford You should not have a branch / tag which is called like a commit message. That would be ... strange.

Comment: In addition I would mention a HTTPS version of `git+` command: `pip install git+https://github.com/gpoore/codebraid@011464539bfb09b8611c8aef0d543532cea958bf`. It may be important for people behind corporate http proxies.

Comment: @LeonardoArroyo that warning is no longer printed as long as you use the full 40 character hash with recent versions of pip. See: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4674

Comment: The git+git://... version of this answer no longer works for GitHub effective today. Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

Comment: You might not need the 'v' at the beginning of the tag name… If you see the `Could not find a tag or branch` consider removing the 'v' and trying again.

Answer (score 32):

It's possible to automatically install a python package using the requirements.txt file on you project just by adding the following line:

`package-name -e git+https://github.com/owner/repository.git@branch_or_commit#egg={package-name}`

and run the command line:

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: For me (pip 9.0.1 in python3.5 virtualenv ) it didn't work : `pip install -r requirements.txt` raised 'Could not detect requirement name, please specify one with #egg='. But it worked with the format '-e git+https://github.com/owner/repository.git#egg=branch_or_commit'

Comment: You need to use this format inside the requirements.txt file. Did you do that?

Comment: I got it working but this is unclear.  Need to have "package_name -e ..." and not just "-e ..." at the start of the line.

Comment: A working example, from a line in my requirements.txt:


`python-openid -e git+https://github.com/openid/python-openid.git@d093a0919198eb53826ae5753e517af10ad95d5b#egg={python-openid}`

Comment: The `package -e url` syntax was not working for me. I'm guessing this was meant to signify an editable build but, well, it was not installing from Github when I tried this. Merely specifying the actual `git+https://github.com/...` URL like in the accepted answer worked for me with pip 19.2.3 on Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 26):

An extra comment to @hugo-tavares's answer:

If it's a private GitHub repository, you'll need to use:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/....
```

In your case:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/aladagemre/django-notification.git@2927346f4c513a217ac8ad076e494dd1adbf70e1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create an egg package, you can still use the same @branch_or_commit appendage: `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myrepo.git@mybranch#egg=myeggscript`