# pip install specific fork

Tags: python, pip, git-fork

I'm trying to `pip install` a specific fork of a repo, which is located here: https://github.com/grutz/flask-session/tree/ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e

Per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch), I've tried the following but no luck:

```
# pip install <link>
pip install https://github.com/grutz/flask-session/tree/ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e

# pip install git+<link>
pip install git+https://github.com/grutz/flask-session/tree/ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e

# pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo@branch
pip install git+https://github.com/grutz/flask-session@ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e

# pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@branch
pip install git+https://github.com/grutz/flask-session.git@ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can post my stack trace but I figured I'm missing something simple here and that would just add clutter.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491790/install-package-with-pip-from-specific-branch-of-github It suggests to put quotes around your URL.

Comment: Try by using quotes around the github url

Comment: @grutz how can I install your forked repo to fix the `session.clear()` issue. Would really appreciate a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pip needs to know the name of the project; name it using `egg=` URL hash param:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/grutz/flask-session.git@ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e#egg=flask-session
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error using this: `Could not find a tag or branch 'ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e', assuming commit.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` Did it work for you?

Comment: Stack trace goes on to say: `Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git' into submodule path '/Users/Jonnymetz/github/src/flask-session/docs/_themes' failed
Failed to clone 'docs/_themes'.` Perhaps this is what's causing the error.

Comment: `Could not find a tag or branch 'ed62129fa1d9af36e77e9ce1de571d2c873a6c4e', assuming commit.` is not an error — just a warning; I also saw it. Repository `git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask-sphinx-themes.git` is public and doesn't require any access right; I cloned it successfully; can you clone it manually?. Command `pip install` above also works for me.

Comment: So you're saying I need to `pip install` or `git clone` that "flask-sphinx-themes" repo before trying to pip install the fork? If so, will `pip install Flask-Sphinx-Themes` achieve this?

Comment: I hope it helps.

Comment: I did a `pip install Flask-Sphinx-Themes` but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately :(

Comment: It appears this extension is no longer maintained. Otherwise this command should have worked!