# How do I force pip to install from the last commit of a branch in a repo?

Tags: python, pip

I want pip to install from the latest commit on a master branch of my github repository. I tried many options mentioned here on StackOverflow, none helped.
For instance, that does not work:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pathToGithubRepo
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685920/install-specific-git-commit-with-pip)? I think if you pip from a git branch it uses the last commit on that branch by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using numpy's repository as an example.

If you know the hash of the commit you are interested in, you can use the following command:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git@75b2d5d427afdb1392f2a0b2092e0767e4bab53d#egg=numpy
```

where `75b2d5d427afdb1392f2a0b2092e0767e4bab53d` is the latest commit for the numpy repository, and `numpy` is the project name used by egg for pip to figure out dependencies.

---

If you want to also automatically get the latest commit hash, you can use the command:

```
$ git ls-remote  git@github.com:numpy/numpy.git | head -1 | awk '{print $1;}'
75b2d5d427afdb1392f2a0b2092e0767e4bab53d
```

---

Unix wasn't invented for nothing, let's combine it into one big command:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git@$(git ls-remote  git@github.com:numpy/numpy.git | head -1 | awk '{print $1;}')#egg=numpy
```

---

Replace numpy with your repository url and project name, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flag `--no-cache-dir` to temporarily disable the cache and avoid installing from an already cached download, instead forcing a download of the most recent commit. ([link to documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=cache#cmdoption-no-cache-dir))

This would look like

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir [path to package location]
```

Using the Chardet package as an example, this could look like:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://github.com/chardet/chardet/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
```