# How to pip install -e with extras and version specifier?

Tags: python, pip

when using:

```
pip install -e pip-package
```

how does one do the equivalent of:

```
pip install pip-package[all]==1.10.0
```

'[all]' being the extra feature I am trying to leverage.

Comment: You can pass extras to editable install. Same as with the package: `pip install -e path/to/package/sources[all]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editable installs can only be performed from a local project or VCS, so you have to download a specific version of the package before.

```
git clone https://github.com/requests/requests.git
cd requests
git checkout tag_name
pip install -e '.[security]'
```

[Install specific git commit with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685920/install-specific-git-commit-with-pip)

[“Editable” Installs docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=-e#editable-installs)