# How to import modified library instead of previously installed one?

Tags: python, github, import

I am new to GitHub and as in the title I am asking for help.
I originally installed the library using pip install. Then I have to make some changes in the code and forked it and downloaded it local. I have made my changes and I am trying to import the modified code in python. I have tried to push it on GitHub but I couldn't find a way to import it from there.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685920/install-specific-git-commit-with-pip ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install specific git commit with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685920/install-specific-git-commit-with-pip)

Answer (score 2):

```
import <module>
```

And use the module in python.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following in the terminal:

```
cd package_dir
pip install .
```

This will replace the original and  install the modified package.

Now you can import your modified package in python

Additionally, if you intend to keep developing the package, you could check this out: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode