# pip cannot install conda==4.8.3 from requirements.txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I was asked to install the libraries contained in a requirements.txt file on a python 3.6 venv.

I do so by executing the bash command:

```
./venv/bin/pip install -r ./ProjectFolder/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

At a certain point the process runs into the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda==4.8.3 (from versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda==4.8.3
```

Indeed in the requirements file there are some conda voices listed:

```
conda==4.8.3
conda-build==3.18.9
conda-package-handling==1.6.0
```

How can I overcome this problem? Is there some other way to install this conda version? Why can't pip find it?
Please I need your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Comment: Conda `requirements.txt` files are not compatible with Pip. Do not install Conda from Pip.

Answer (score -1):

The `conda` package on PyPI seems to be not being updated anymore.
So the only way i see right now to download it via pip would be using `pip`'s feature for downloading packages from a git repository.

The specific `conda` version you want to install is stored as a tag on their GitHub repository and should be installable via:

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/conda/conda@4.8.3
```

For more informations you can visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754517/13891412)
or directly take a look at the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/vcs-support/)

Comment: Conda cannot properly be installed using Pip.